# Cannot build frontend docker image properly cause NPM throw code E400

Tags: npm, dockerfile, npm-install

I trying to build docker image of my frontend app. But i got this exception

```
Step 9/12 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in b1d123456789
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmmirror.com/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.13.1.tgz
```

And this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN npm config set proxy http://internal.domain.com
RUN npm config set @commons:registry=http://internal.domain.com:8080/repository/npm-releases
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/

WORKDIR /src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

IMO some `npm config` may be are necessary

PS

I ran  `curl -v https://registry.npmjs.com/` and return HTTP 200
and i can download https://registry.npmmirror.com/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.13.1.tgz manually.

Anybody has tip how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Chances are the problem comes from your proxy. Are you using the same proxy when using curl manually? Did you check that the proxy is letting you through correctly on the target where you build the image?